# TypeScript in a JavaScript Angular Project - Argument is 'SearchCtrl' is not a function or is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to set up an angular search controller in a project that has existing JavaScript code, using TypeScript.

below is my controller.

```
/// <reference path="../Models/ISearchSrvc.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Services/searchSrvc.ts"/>
module GLA.Controllers {
    export class SearchCtrl {
        searchService: Services.SearchSrvc;
        searchTerms: string;
        pattern: RegExp = /^\s*\w*\s*$/;
        static $inject = ["Services.SearchSrvc"];
        constuctor(service: Services.SearchSrvc) {
            this.searchService = service;
        }
        searchResults: Models.IResultsContainer;
        getSearch = () => {
            this.searchResults = this.searchService.search(this.searchTerms);
        }
    }
    angular.module("GLA").controller("GLA.Controllers.SearchCtrl", SearchCtrl);
}
```

I then import them in the shared _Layout page of the project

```
<script src="~/Angular/Services/searchSrvc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Angular/Controllers/searchCtrl.js"></script>
```

Then when use ng-controller to define a div I want to use the controller on, I get `Argument 'SearchCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`,

However, if I create a controller in JS, like below:

```
GLA.controller('testCtrl',['$scope','searchSrvc', function($scopt, searchSrvc) {
$scopt.whatwhat = "whatwhat!!";
}])
```

This controller can be used on any Div within my project.
Any kind of help would be really appreciated!

I have been over this with other developers and as no one bar myself has done much in TypeScript, we've not had any luck, however I am certain other parts have been implemented correctly, its just the issue of a typescript controller in a JavaScript project maybe?

Below is the compiled Controller:

```
/// <reference path="../Models/ISearchSrvc.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Services/searchSrvc.ts"/>
alert("loaded");
var GLA;
(function(GLA) {
    var Controllers;
    (function(Controllers) {
        var SearchCtrl = (function() {
            function SearchCtrl() {
                var _this = this;
                this.pattern = /^\s*\w*\s*$/;
                this.getSearch = function() {
                    _this.searchResults = _this.searchService.search(_this.searchTerms);
                };
            }
            SearchCtrl.prototype.constuctor = function(service) {
                this.searchService = service;
            };
            SearchCtrl.$inject = ["Services.SearchSrvc"];
            return SearchCtrl;
        }());
        Controllers.SearchCtrl = SearchCtrl;
        angular.module("GLA").controller("GLA.Controllers.SearchCtrl", SearchCtrl);
    })(Controllers = GLA.Controllers || (GLA.Controllers = {}));
})(GLA || (GLA = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=searchCtrl.js.map
```

Comment: Have you looked at the generated JavaScript from the TypeScript source ?

Comment: do you get any console errors ?

Comment: @MiteshPant The only error in the console is the one that refers to the Controller not being a Function/Undefined :-/

Comment: @Bludwarf I have, I'm very new to JavaScript, so not completely sure what I'm looking at. I find typescript a little easier because of its similarities with C# and other OOP languages. I'll add the controller to the question, I've added an alert to make sure its being loaded.

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause, but you have a typo in your constRuctor method `constuctor(service: Services.SearchSrvc)`

Comment: @MattM its not the issue, but it was definitely wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out eventually,

below is the line that was causing me grief:

`angular.module("GLA").controller("GLA.Controllers.SearchCtrl", SearchCtrl);`

Changed it to:

`angular.module("GLA").controller("SearchCtrl", SearchCtrl);`
removing the `GLA.Controllers`

This made controller available globally, however I am unsure what this string represents, or why it was invalid with the `GLA.Controller`, as I have built it similarly in other projects.